# Godot: Move_and_slide_with_snap not working on slopes

Tags: physics, movement, platformer, godot, character

**My Problem**

I am currently building a platformer game. I was attempting to use move_and_slide_with_snap for the first time and can't find it working for me. My character does snap to the ground like I expected, but I find that it still slides when it's on a slope. I *think* that I implemented the code properly with it.

If there is a solution I would love to hear it. What am I doing wrong?

```
func _physics_process(delta):


var current_gravity = GRAVITY - (int(is_on_wall() and inventory.Frog) * GRAVITY/2)
var current_jump_force = JUMP_FORCE

var x_input = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")

if x_input != 0:

    motion.x += x_input * ACCELERATION * delta
    motion.x = clamp(motion.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)

else:

    playback.travel("Stand")

if !is_on_wall():
    if motion.y <= max_fall_speed:
        motion.y += current_gravity * delta
else:
    if motion.y <= max_slip_speed:
        motion.y += current_gravity * delta
    

if is_on_floor() or is_on_wall():
    if x_input == 0:
        motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, FRICTION)
        
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        var can_jump = int(inventory.Spring)
        motion.y = -(current_jump_force + (JUMP_FORCE / 2.5 * can_jump))
else:
    
    if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and motion.y < -JUMP_FORCE/2:
        motion.y = -current_jump_force/2
    
    if x_input == 0:
        motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, AIR_RESISTANCE)

if !motion.y:
    motion = move_and_slide_with_snap(motion, Vector2.DOWN * 320, Vector2.UP, true, 1)
else:
    motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time. For me, the solution was centered around having a correct `snap` vector. Using `get_floor_normal()` as `snap` when not jumping resolved my problem. For example:

```
snap = get_floor_normal()
if is_on_floor():
  if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
    snap = Vector3.ZERO

move_and_slide_with_snap(velocity, snap, Vector3.UP, true, 4, max_slope_angle)
```

I took this example code from my own project which is why I have `Vector3`'s. I believe it will work just the same for `Vector2`. Let me know if this solves the problem for you.

Comment: You may also need to clamp your velocity. More information can be found [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/34117#issuecomment-562841402)